# Prove that $A - B = A $ iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have a lemma below:

$${A}-{B} = {A} \Longleftrightarrow A \cap B = \emptyset.$$

I start with the $\Longrightarrow$:

$$\text{Suppose}\ x \in {A}-{B},\text{then}\  x \in A\ \text{but}\  x \notin B.$$

$${A}-{B} = {A}\ \text{so}\ x \in A\ \text{but}\ x \notin B \equiv x \in A.$$

So the fact that $x \notin B$ does not matter at all. It's getting confused because this lemma is just proved to prove this theorem:

$$P(A-B) = P(A) \Longleftrightarrow A \cap B = \emptyset.$$

With the lemma, I can prove the theorem. Anyone has any advice on how to prove the lemma? Thank you!

Comment: If you show the first direction, then let $x\in A\cap B$ and show a contradiction: if there is one, then considering an element $x\in A\cap B$ is nonsense, hence $A\cap B$ must be empty.

Comment: You just have to check that if  $A\setminus B\varsubsetneq A$, then $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$ and conversely. It seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hi, P doesn't stand for probability here. It is the power set

Comment: Whoops, never mind then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there. You have "$x\in A$ and $x\notin B$" $\Longleftrightarrow$ "$x\in A$". In particular, $x\in A \Longrightarrow x\notin B$, meaning that there is no $x$ for which $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, so $A\cap B$ is empty.

Conversely, if $A\cap B$ is empty then for any $x\in A$ we have $x\notin B$, so $x\in A\Longrightarrow x\notin B\Longrightarrow(x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B)$, and clearly $(x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B)\Longrightarrow x\in A$.

Comment: Can you do the $\Longleftarrow$ please? I see other comments lacking something or confusing.

Comment: @hanamontana Sure, have added this.

Answer (score 0):

$A-B$ is defined as $\{a \in A : a \notin B\}$. Then,
$$A-B=A \iff \{a \in A : a \notin B\} =A \iff \{a \in A : a \in B\}= \phi$$
Now, $\{a \in A : a \in B\} = A \cap B$ by definition, so we're done.

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$ We prove the contrapositive statement: $A\cap B\neq\emptyset \Rightarrow A-B\neq A$.

$A\cap B\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow $there exists $x\in A\cap B$ i.e. $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ so $x\in A$ and $x\notin A-B$ thus $A-B\neq A$ (there exists one element, namely $x$, that belongs to one set, $A$, but not to $A-B$).

$\Leftarrow$ We first note that $A-B\subset A$. Now $x\in A\Rightarrow x\notin B$ since $A\cap B =\emptyset$ so it must be $x\in A-B$ thus it is also $A\subset A-B$ which implies that $A-B=A$ and this concludes the proof.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain "it is also $A-B\subset A$ which implies that $A-B=A$", please? I understand every step except for that one.

Comment: @hanamontana it was a typo (it's $A\subset A-B$), now corrected

Comment: hi, it's still confusing. I tried to rewrite your proof this way: Suppose A $\cap$ B = $\emptyset$, then "x $\in$ A but x $\notin$ B." 

So it must be x $\in$ A - B.

Comment: That's the last thing I understand. How you can conclude A $\subset$ A - B from that? Can you explain to me please in a bit more detailed?

Comment: @hanamontana you can conclude that because you took an **arbitrary** $x\in A$ and reasoned that (since $A\cap B=\emptyset $) it belongs to $A-B$ so that must conclusion must be valid for any $x\in A$ i.e. every element of $A$ is also an element of $A-B$ so, by definition of subset, $A\subset A-B$.

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap B'=A\Longrightarrow$ $$A\cap B=(A\cap B')\cap B= A\cap (B'\cap B)=A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset $$
$A\cap B=\emptyset\Longrightarrow$
$$A\cap B'=(A\cap B')\cup(A\cap B)=A\cap(B'\cup B)=A$$